# Create symlink if source exists

Tags: linux, centos6, shell, unix-shell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make a symlink to a directory if it exists only and cannot figure out how.

I tried various ideas I found and none worked.
Most notable idea that i thought would do the job was to use `ln -s ls /path` to test the dir for `ln` but it did not work or I'm not doing it right.

This is the basic symlink command I'm trying to condition.

```
ln -s ~/public_html/images ./images
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ -d ~/public_html/images ] && ln -s ~/public_html/images ./images
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu use

```
ls ./public_html/images && ln -s ~/public_html/images ./images
```

The first command (list content of *./public_html/images*) will fail if *./public_html/images* does not exist. Due to double ampersand (&&) the second command (create soft link) will only run if first command succeeds.